# How do I find malware in my Wordpress Directory?

Tags: wordpress, malware, websecurity

What are the most common hack files you would find in your wordpress directory. So far I have found huh.php, 365.php, le.php, back.zip, login.zip and a folder /pp with a bunch of fake php files. What else should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below steps to remove malware from the WordPress directory.

```
Step 1: Backup the Site Files and Database
Step 2: Download and Examine the Backup Files
Step 3: Delete All the Files in the public_html folder
Step 4: Reinstall WordPress
Step 5: Reset Passwords and Permalinks
Step 6: Reinstall Plugins
Step 7: Reinstall Themes
Step 8: Upload Your Images from the Backup
Step 9: Install and Run Security Plugins
```